# Adding a 3rd Option to Questionnaire for "Select an Option"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a questionnaire and if the user selects Option 1 or 2 for `Select an Option` what they select determines the link that is displayed at the end of the questionnaire.  Instead of only 2 options, I would like to have 3 options for `Select an Option`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a id="q1_one" class="step_button next" href="javascript:void(0)">option 1</a>
<a id="q1_two" class="step_button next" href="javascript:void(0)">option 2</a>
```

This is where I would like to add a `q1_three` but I'm not sure how to get it to work

The Javascript:

```
function run_loading_run_4(time_delay, q1) {
timeoutID3 = window.setTimeout(
function() {
        run_loading_4(q1);
},
time_delay);
}

function run_loading_4(q1) {
    $('.run_loading_4, .loading').hide();
    $('.li_run_loading_4, li_run_loading_5, .run_loading_5, .show_end').fadeIn();
    $('#' + q1).show();
    }
$(function () {

var q1;

$(document).on('click', '.next', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    if ($(this).attr('id') === "q1_one") {
            q1 = "yes";
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === "q1_two") {
            q1 = "no";
    }

});
$(document).on('click', '.run_loading', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    $('.step4 .loading').show();
    run_loading_run_1('2000');
    run_loading_run_2('4500');
    run_loading_run_3('6500');
    run_loading_run_4('8900',q1);

    });
});
```

and the answers: that are displayed depending if option 1 or 2 is selected.

```
<div id="yes">
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">I Agree</a>
</div>
<div id="no">
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link2.com">I Agree</a>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8r6eH/

Comment: Hi you have not specified what you would like to do when someone click on option3.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add option by add following lines:
HTML(line#5 and #37);

```
<h2>Select An Option</h2>
<a id="q1_one" class="step_button next" href="javascript:void(0)">Option 1</a>
<a id="q1_two" class="step_button next" href="javascript:void(0)">Option 2</a>
<a id="q1_three" class="step_button next" href="javascript:void(0)">Option 3</a>

<div id="yes">
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link2.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 1</a>
</div>
<div id="no">
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 2</a>
</div>
<div id="3rd_option">
    <a class="step_button" href="http://link1.com">IF QUESTION 1 = Option 3</a>
</div>
```

and javascript(line#57):

```
if ($(this).attr('id') === "q1_one") {
    q1 = "yes";
} else if ($(this).attr('id') === "q1_two") {
    q1 = "no";
} else if ($(this).attr('id') === "q1_three") {
    q1 = "3rd_option";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r6eH/1/)